# CSS all placeholder (*) affects my styles

Tags: html, css

This code doesn't apply the width of my div

```
.column-hide {
    width: 16.666666666666664%!important;
}

.column-hide * {
    display: none;
}
```

While this works

```
.column-hide * {
    display: none;
}

.column-hide {
    width: 16.666666666666664%!important;
}
```

Any advice?

UPDATE: HTML CODE

```
<div class="col-md-6 column-hide">
    <div class="header-label bg-gray custom-attr-header">
    </div>
    <div class="fields-body">
        <h4 class="pull-left">Texts</h4>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: .column-hide is the parent div by the way that holds all my elements

Comment: can you please paste you html code??

Comment: What you tried to achieve here ?

Comment: How do you infer that some setting is not applied to an element when you set display: none on all its descendants? Looking at the document in browser developer tools shows that the setting *is* applied, it just has no visible effect since the height is 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An Asterisk (*) is the universal selector for CSS. It matches a single element of any type. So I;ll not suggest to avoid this `universal selector`. I felt many time if you define same property the last one applied always.

Here is the ***[Working Example](http://jsbin.com/gafefebe/1/)***.

here is the HTML code and CSS. The last one property will apply to element.

```
p{color:red;}

p{color:green;} /*will take me as I am defined at last*/

<p>I'll be RED</p>
<p>I'll be GREEN</p>
```

As you can see the `color:green` applied at last so `<p>` element color will be green. same theory will apply in your case as well.

Comment: I got rid of using this *. Fixed my problem. And yes you are right about sequence of styling. Thanks.

Comment: The question was why a width is not applied. This does not address that question.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela if the answer is accepted by the user, it means the suggestion works for him. I don't understand here giving the negative voting. Also I've explained already and don't think again I've to explain..

Comment: What matters here is whether an answer addresses the question that was asked. This one does not. The question is obscure, but as asked, it is about a width setting.

Answer (score 0):

```
* {
display:none
}
```

will shows no element of html as * means all element.By using current posted code nothing is showing up. In order to display the content need to remove the above property